# Downstream IBM Httpd Server returns 404 only when accessed through another upstream IHS web server

Tags: configuration, java, port, websphere, ihs

We have a current setup like the following:

- HTTPServer - IBM HTTPD Server v?
- WASServer6.1 - WebSphere Application Server v6.1 (Running App "A")

The basic communication is as follows on the listed ports. [All port numbers listed are the listening ports.] The `plugin-cfg.xml` is appropriately configured, and this same topology has been operating in a Production environment for 6+ years.

```
HTTPServer:8080 --> WASServer6.1:9081
```

We now need to adapt in these new things, changing the topology somewhat:

- IHSServer - IBM HTTPD Server v? (newer than above)
- WASServer8.5 - WebSphere Application Server v8.5.5 (Running App "B")
- AuthService - Stand-alone Java service (not running in app container)

  ```
  HTTPServer:8080 ---> AuthService:9090 ---> IHSServer:8081 ---> WASServer8.5:9081
                  \
                   \
                    WASServer6.1:9081
  ```

**HTTPServer** has `httpd.conf` configured with `ProxyPass` directives that proxy certain requests to **AuthService:9090**.  AuthService does some work, and then copies the headers of the request into a new [POST] request that is sent to **IHSServer:8081**, where the `plugin-cfg.xml` is mapped with the App B information to forward requests on to App B running on **WASServer8.5**.  The ultimate goal is to take advantage of the plugin's state-awareness of the WAS JVMs.  In our Production-level environment, there would be multiple JVMs to which IHS could forward requests.
**NOTE:**  The AuthService is stateless, and so there is no need for any affinity to a particular JVM on WAS.

The problem is that this doesn't work for some reason.  Requests sent through this path return with a `HTTP 404` from **IHSServer**.

Troubleshooting with verbose logging for **IHSServer** has revealed that for some reason IHSServer is seeing the port number of the original forwarding proxy (HTTPServer:8080) and comparing it to the `VirtualHostGroup` virtualhosts listing in the `plugin-cfg.xml` (Why?).  Finding no suitable match for port 8080, it gives up and spits out a 404.

If we replace things, as below, by first hitting some other Apache server listening on Port 80:

```
    SomeOtherHTTPServer:80 ---> AuthService:9090 ---> IHSServer:8081 ---> WASServer8.5:9081
                       \
                        \
                         WASServer:9081
```

...the request is accepted by IHSServer and things work properly.  Similarly, if an appropriately-formed request payload is sent directly to AuthService:9090, the request is accepted and everything works.

We attempted to add `<VirtualHost Name="*:8080"/>` to the `plugin-cfg.xml` on **IHSServer**, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

**EDIT:** We've taken some `tcpdump` captures at every node along this pathway, and it's clear that **IHSServer** immediately rejects requests with a 404 when they've come through the **HTTPServer:8080**.  IHSServer doesn't even attempt to do anything with the request.

**What other things could we do to troubleshoot/correct this?  Why does the plugin on IHSServer care about the listening port of an upstream web server?**

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see "ProxyPreserveHost" in your post.  Have you tried it?

It seems to me a likely cause for a 404 generated by the IHS server on port 8081 (due to no match in plugin-cfg.xml and handled as a static file) or by the AppServer itself (when it checks its own notion of host aliasts to determine a web app mapping).

Comment: At which point would that come into play?  In my example above, which host would need that directive?

Comment: The one with proxypass

Answer (score 0):

You possibly need to also add the Virtual host alias `VirtualHost Name="*:8080"` in `WASServer8.5` too.
Then restart the WAS 8.5 server to take the change and this should work.

Generally, you need to configure the Virtual host(*:8080) in all levels from IHS conf to WAS plug-in to WAS VirtualHosts.